# Customizing User Profile in Django

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

I would like to add new fields at user profile. Its working on *admin* side but it isnt saving on frontend... 
Its very curious because no error is showing, it just doenst save.

In the following code I added the field "CPF" to userprofile. Its showed correctly in the frontend form and then I try to save it (some problem happen here)

I appreciate any help.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

...
cpf = models.CharField('CPF',max_length=14)
...

def __unicode__(self):
return self.cpf
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from usuario.models import UserProfile


class cadastroForm(UserCreationForm):
...

cpf = forms.CharField(label='CPF')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username", "cpf")


def save(self, commit=True):
    ...
    user.cpf = self.cleaned_data["cpf"]

    if commit:
        user.save()

    return user
```

views.py

```
def cadastro(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = cadastroForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
else:
    form = cadastroForm()
return render_to_response("registration/registration.html", {
    'form': form,
})
```

admin.py (its working fine, dont need any change)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from usuario.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AuthUserAdmin

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = UserProfile
max_num = 1
can_delete = False

class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
   inlines = [UserProfileInline]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Show you full model, is the `cpf` field on some custom `User` or `UserProfile` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in commit conditional, the solution was:

```
        if commit:            
           user.save()
           profile.user = user
           profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell since you didn't post all of the code. Can you post all code so we can see if it is a typo somewhere and so we can tell what user is, in your modelform.

Are you calling the super save in your modelform's save method? Can't remember if it is required or not.

## not real code just an example

m = super(yourForm, self).save()